# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: sitecore-client, installation

I am trying to move media items from local machine to dev server via Sitecore packages and I getting errors while installing it.

I have two separate packages, one for media images (size 4.6GB) and another one is for media files(pdf,docs etc) (size 2.47GB) and getting different errors with both these packages.

Source and target Sitecore Version - 9.3.0

Any thoughts?

[image]

```
Could not read signature - no data!
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not read signature - no data!

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[Exception: Could not read signature - no data!]
   Sitecore.Zip.ZipEntry.ReadSignature(Stream s) +157
   Sitecore.Zip.ZipEntry.ReadHeader(Stream s, ZipEntry ze, Encoding nameEncoding) +29
   Sitecore.Zip.ZipEntry.Read(Stream s, Encoding nameEncoding) +45
   Sitecore.Zip.<get_Entries>d__8.MoveNext() +81
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +548
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.LoadPackage() +436
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.ActivePageChanging(String page, String& newpage) +93
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Pages.WizardForm.set_Active(String value) +106
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Button.DoClick(Message message) +60

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Component.HandleMessage(Message message) +195
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ClientEventCommand.SendEventMessage() +131
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ClientEventCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +16
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent() +98
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +806
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479
```

[image]

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: count
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: count

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: count]
   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ValidateParameters(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +217
   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +47
   Sitecore.Zip.Utils.LimitedReadOnlyStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +104
   Sitecore.Install.StreamUtil.Copy(Stream from, Stream to, Int32 bufferSize) +59
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +256
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.LoadPackage() +436
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.ActivePageChanging(String page, String& newpage) +93
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Pages.WizardForm.set_Active(String value) +106
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Button.DoClick(Message message) +60

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Component.HandleMessage(Message message) +195
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ClientEventCommand.SendEventMessage() +131
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ClientEventCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +16
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent() +98
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +806
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479
```

Comment: How did you create these packages?

Comment: I used standard Sitecore Package Designer to create these packages.

Comment: @SuryaNarayan I would suggest disabling `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` where there is an event called `packageinstall:items:ended` It will increase your package installation.

Comment: Don't use packages for transferring large amounts of data like that. Use a tool like Sitecore Sidekick, SPS Content Migrator or RAZL. Packages will not cope with that amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following approach to overcome this issue.

1. Used Developer Tab > Serialize Tree to serialize content
2. Created a zip of serialized content and moved to server
3. Used Developer Tab > Update Tree to deserialize content
4. Faced slow serialization issue
5. Googled and found that this is an issue and Sitecore has hotfix for it
6. Applied [hotfix](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0539394)
7. Re-ran deserialization using Developer Tab > Update Tree
8. Done

Answer (score 2):

As per best practice, Sitecore package size should be less than 2 GB. Its an old known issue and I guess applicable for Sitecore 9.3 as well. See this KB article - https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0287164

Please create a few packages smaller than the maximum allowable size 2047 MB (1.9 GB) instead of creating a single large one.

Comment: Thanks @Mahendra for sharing the link for known issue. It was helpful for taking next steps. However, it was difficult for me to create smaller packages as there are lots of media items and folders and one of the folders in the deep hierarchy is big in size.